# New Twitter Widget

Tags: api, widget, twitter

i can't remove (twitter widget v1.1) header and footer

Code generated by twitter widget :

```
<a class="twitter-timeline" href="https://twitter.com/MonTy_Adel" data-widget-id="261143811491774464">Tweets by @MonTy_Adel</a>

<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script>
```

this code belong to twitter widget v1.0 but NOT WORKING :

```
.twtr-hd, .twtr-ft
{
display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add to href this attribute 
data-chrome="nofooter noheader"

like that :

```
<a class="twitter-timeline" href="@user_name" data-widget-id="app_id" data-chrome="nofooter noheader" >Tweets from @user_name</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try adding !important to the end of the of display:none; it should read

```
.twtr-hd, .twtr-ft
{
display: none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot style elements inside of an iframe from a stylesheet on your domain. Instead, you'll have to inject the styles into the iframe. [See this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217776/how-to-apply-css-to-iframe).